# Adding Related Articles to post

Tags: tags

Been pulling my hair out trying to get related articles going. I've tried a few methods but this is the only one that has given me results but random posts are shown rather than posts related to it by article.

```
<?php           
    $args=array('tag_in'=>$tags,
    'exclude'=>$post->ID,
    'post_per_page'=> 4,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1,
    'post_type'=>array('ms','gnd','events','news_article','opinions','projects','tenders','videos','products'));
    $rel_pst=get_posts($args);
    $count = 0;
    if($tags){
        foreach($rel_pst as $rel):setup_postdata($rel);//Loop through and find related posts
            if($count==4)
            {
                break;
            }
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id($rel->ID),'related-posts');
        //$tagy=$tags[$count];
        //Counts iterations to place aricles on seperate sides 


        if (($count  == 0)||($count == 2)){// first article start
            echo '<div class="posts_wrapper">';
            echo '<article class="item_left">';
        }
        if(($count == 1)||($count == 3)){// second article start
            echo'<article class="item_right">';
        }
?>  
<div class="pic"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($rel); ?>" class="w_hover img-link img-wrap"> <?php echo $image; ?></a> </div>
<h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($rel);?>"><?php echo get_the_title($rel); ?></a></h3>
<div class="post-info"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($rel);?>" class="post_date"></a> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($rel); ?>" class="comments_count"></a> </div>
</article>
<?php 
    if(($count == 1)||($count == 3)){//second article/4th end
        echo '</div>';
    }   
        $count ++;
        endforeach;
    }           
//wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's `tag__in` (two underscores) 2) `get_the_tags()` returns an array of *objects*, you need IDs:

```
if ( $the_tags = get_the_tags() ) {
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/
    $the_tags = wp_list_pluck( $the_tags, 'term_id' );
}

$rel_pst = get_posts( array(
    'tag__in'             => $the_tags,
    'exclude'             => $post->ID,
    'post_per_page'       => 4,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'post_type'           => array(
        'ms',
        'gnd',
        'events',
        'news_article',
        'opinions',
        'projects',
        'tenders',
        'videos',
        'products',
    ),
));

if ( $rel_pst ) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: I will except this as an answer as it works!! Thanks DeadMedic, I owe you one :)

Answer (score 1):

Whithout knowing the value of `$tags` variable (you are not showing it to us), the only thing I see wrong in your code is the `tag_in` argumente, the correct one is `tag__in` (note the double `_`).

Also, note that `tag__in` works with the core tag taxonomy. This taxonomy is not supported by custom post types by default, only by the standard post type.

Comment: Ah interesting, so do you have any suggestions for custom post types? Or how I can go about comparing tags of a post against all post types with the same tag(s). Also changing the query to tag__in breaks the query and no results are displayed

Comment: Oh and `$tags` is 
`$tags=get_the_tags();`
From the original post

Comment: +1 For opening the discussion for `$tags` and highlighting the `tag_in` typo.